# How can I get a Ruby Script to take a CSV File and separate it to get a specific output?

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing, scripting

The goal of the script is to get the last name and the first and last letter of the first name and provide is as an eventual username for the useradd command. An example of this is: John Doe, The desired username would be doejn.

I can get the CSV file read into the script by using this:
(The CSV File has a Header of "First Name" and "Last Name")

```
employeeData = CSV.parse(File.read("employeedata.csv"), headers: true)
```

After that I have no clue how to use the data that is in the employeeData variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering your `employeedata.csv` having a header with `First Name` and `Last Name` column

e.g of CSV file

```
First Name, Last Name
Rohit, Lingayat

filename = 'employeedata.csv' #*location of the file*

CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
   first_name_char = row['First Name'].strip.split('')
   useradd_name = "#{row['Last Name']}#{first_name_char.first}#{first_name_char.last}"
   puts useradd_name
end
```

**output:**

```
LingayatRt
```

You can use `useradd_name` to use in your command or you can create an array which will be the list of all combinations of the first name and last name and you can use accordingly.

hope this solution will help you out.

Comment: If I keep the `file` variable just before `headers:` it errors out. And when I put the path to the CSV in its spot it also errors out.

Comment: what is the error? you need to specify the location of the file

Comment: file != filename